# AS3 - Buttons do not work upon reentering frame

Tags: actionscript-3, function, button, mouseevent, listener

I've set up three buttons in the first frame which are supposed to switch frames. When the program first runs, there are no errors, and i can click any of the buttons and end up where I want. However, when going back to the first frame, the buttons no longer work. The stage listener still works though. I added the "Clicked" output to check if the function was called, which it wasn't. I know I disable the buttons in the code, but only after that button is clicked, and the task is done. I should mention I don't have the code on the timeline, but on a separate document. Here is my code:

```
package{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
public class DocumentClass extends MovieClip
{
    public var matteOppgave:Boolean = false;
    public var engelskOppgave:Boolean = false;
    public var flaggOppgave:Boolean = false;

    public function DocumentClass()
    {
        stop();


        btnBok.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, matte);
        btnFlagg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, flagg);
        btnPc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, engelsk);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, sjekk);


        btnBok.enabled = true;
        btnPc.enabled = true;
        btnFlagg.enabled = true;

        function matte(evt:MouseEvent)
        {
            gotoAndStop(2);
            frame2();
            trace("Clicked");
        }

        function engelsk(evt:MouseEvent)
        {
            gotoAndStop(3);
            frame3();
            trace("Clicked");
        }

        function flagg(evt:MouseEvent)
        {
            gotoAndStop(4);
            frame4();
            trace("Clicked");
        }
        function sjekk(evt:Event)
        {
            if(matteOppgave == true && engelskOppgave == true && flaggOppgave == true)
            {
                gotoAndStop(5);
            }

            if(matteOppgave == true)
            {
                btnBok.alpha = 0.5;
                btnBok.enabled = false;
                låsEin.alpha = 0;
            }
            if(engelskOppgave == true)
            {
                btnPc.alpha = 0.5;
                btnPc.enabled = false;
                låsTo.alpha = 0;
            }
            if(flaggOppgave == true)
            {
                btnFlagg.alpha = 0.5;
                btnFlagg.enabled = false;
                låsTre.alpha = 0;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: How DO you get back to frame 1?

Comment: When the program has ran through all of the codes in the functions (frame2, frame3 and frame4), I assumed it continued in the first function (DocumentClass)... The listener for the stage works after going back to frame1, so I guess it works that way. If you mean on the timeline, then I have a gotoAndStop(1) in the end of the functions.

Comment: "...in the end of the functions."  What does this mean? That you automatically go back to frame 1, from frames 2,3 and 4, after each button is clicked?    Also, how to you set to 'true' your 'matteOppgave,' 'engelskOppgave,' and 'flaggOppgave.'  If you had given all of this information to begin with you might have had an answer by now!

Comment: When clicking btnBok, frame2 is played, a task is solved by the user, matteOppgave is set to true, the first frame on the timeline is shown (with the gotoAndStop(1), and the frame2 fuction is done. When the frame2 function is done, the code continues in the DocumentClass function.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working from a solution posted on another forum. I made the five frames i had into movieclips, and changed back and forth using addChild() and removeChild().